# Two-way communication between Excel and my C# program

Tags: c#, excel

I want to have a two-way communication between Excel and my C# program. When some data changes in Excel, I need to know (in real time) what changed in Excel. In the other direction, based on some events, I want to update Excel worksheet (in real time). Eventually, my program will be deployed onto a Windows Server.

Can you please suggest what are the best ways to do this?

Comment: What platform is your program written in?

Comment: C# using Visual Studio 2010

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want to follow all changes made in a workbook. For that you might need the Worksheet_Change event as described [here](http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/run-macros-change.htm). You will need to set the Target argument to the area (Range,Worksheet) you're supervising. You could be able to build a log with the changes that are made to the Target ranges. The second part of your question is pretty vague, what events are we talking about ? Worksheet_Change might be the answer again but more information is needed.

Comment: I am aware of the Change event from Excel and am passing the corresponding cell changes to my program using a COM Component. The COM component essentially connects to our database server and records these changes. Similarly other users of our tool will also be changing some pieces of information. My program can access the database using a server component and retrieve changes others made. As and when such a change happens in our database I need to update the Excel spreadsheet without any user intervention.